# Android json parse with Retrofit library

Tags: android, json, rest, asp.net-web-api, retrofit2

I found the following json formated file . Is it possible to parse with retrofit ? Generally json has key and value for each section but here one array has key and others array has values . so How to parse it ?

```
{
  "insertnewdatas": {
    "columns": [
      "id",
      "operatorName",
      "latitude",
      "longitude",
      "location",
      "address",
      "currencies",
      "exchange",
      "exchangeLimits",
      "workingDays",
      "link",
      "phone",
      "email",
      "dateTime",
      "created_at",
      "updated_at"
    ],
    "records": [
      [
        3,
        "Coin Source",
        "22.3475",
        "91.8123",
        "Chittagong",
        "Oxygen , Chittagong",
        "Cash",
        "option2",
        "$500/month",
        "30",
        "no link",
        "017000000000",
        "arifhasnat.info@gmail.com",
        "21-10-2017",
        "2017-03-01 17:40:42",
        "2017-03-01 17:40:42"
      ],
      [
        4,
        "Coin Source",
        "22.3475",
        "91.8123",
        "Chittagong",
        "Oxygen , Chittagong",
        "Cash",
        "option2",
        "$500/month",
        "30",
        "no link",
        "017000000000",
        "arifhasnat.info@gmail.com",
        "21-10-2017",
        "2017-03-01 17:40:49",
        "2017-03-01 17:40:49"
      ],
      [
        5,
        "Bit Coin",
        "22.3575",
        "91.8323",
        "Chittagong",
        "Chittagong",
        "both",
        "option1",
        "$500/month",
        "30",
        "no link",
        "017000000000",
        "arifhasnat.info@gmail.com",
        "21-10-2017",
        "2017-03-01 17:43:34",
        "2017-03-01 17:43:34"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: that's a pretty bad format. I would recommend you start by trying to change it

Answer (score 2):

By default Retrofit does not support an automated JSON parsing. But you can use GSON for that. https://github.com/google/gson

A short tutorial how to parse JSON with Retrofit and GSON you can find for example here: http://www.pratikbutani.com/2016/05/android-tutorial-json-parsing-using-retrofit-part-1/

But there are much more tutorials out there which will help you.

Comment: I know that json parse with retrofit but this format is possible ? has there any example for that format ?